# Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem Question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Consider the action of a group $G$ of order $900$ on a set $X$ with cardinality $15$. By using the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem, what is the value for the order of the stabiliser of a point of $X$?

So I know that the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem states that:
$$
|G|=|\operatorname{Stab}(x)|\times |\operatorname{Orb}(x)|
$$
But I'm not sure this can be applied to the problem at hand, nor how to approach this question. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a fixed answer for this unless you have more assumptions, for example perhaps the action is transitive?

Comment: @AugustLiu There are a few possible orders I have been provided: 80, 120, 45,150.

Answer (score 5):

Stabilizers are subgroups, so $80$ and $120$ are ruled out by Lagrange's theorem. Then, $45$ would lead to $|O(x)|=20$, which can't be because the orbits partiton $X$, whose size is $15$. So you are left with $150$ as possible order of a stabilizer.